# Cassandra - failure to start, with error "Insufficient disk space to write 572 bytes"

Tags: java, cassandra, jvm, runtimeexception

I am getting this error, trying to launch Cassandra. I ran `rm -rf *` on `/var/log/cassandra` and `/var/lib/cassandra`, and try to run `cassandra` again, with no success. Any idea? I have been looking to similar cases, but not at the launch of Cassandra, and nothing I found helped me to solve this problem.

```
root@test # cassandra
(...)
16:38:38.551 [MemtableFlushWriter:1] ERROR o.a.c.service.CassandraDaemon - Exception in thread Thread[MemtableFlushWriter:1,5,main]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Insufficient disk space to write 572 bytes
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Directories.getWriteableLocation(Directories.java:349) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable.flush(Memtable.java:324) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore$Flush.run(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1165) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
16:38:41.785 [ScheduledTasks:1] INFO  o.a.cassandra.locator.TokenMetadata - Updating topology for all endpoints that have changed
```

FYI, if I try to run `cassandra` again just after, I got

```
[main] ERROR o.a.c.service.CassandraDaemon - Port already in use: 7199; nested exception is:
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

So it seems that "CassandraDaemon" is alive; but if I want to run `cqlsh` I got this error:

```
root@test # cqlsh
Warning: custom timestamp format specified in cqlshrc, but local timezone could not be detected.
Either install Python 'tzlocal' module for auto-detection or specify client timezone in your cqlshrc.

Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

Finally, the `free -m` command gives me

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15758        8308         950        1440        6499        5576
Swap:          4095        2135        1960
```

Thanks for you help!

EDIT : Here are the WARN message I got during Cassandra launch:

```
11:36:14.622 [main] WARN  o.a.c.config.DatabaseDescriptor - Small commitlog volume detected at /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog; setting commitlog_total_space_in_mb to 2487.  You can override this in cassandra.yaml
11:36:14.623 [main] WARN  o.a.c.config.DatabaseDescriptor - Only 17 MB free across all data volumes. Consider adding more capacity to your cluster or removing obsolete snapshots
11:36:14.943 [main] WARN  o.a.cassandra.service.StartupChecks - jemalloc shared library could not be preloaded to speed up memory allocations
11:36:14.943 [main] WARN  o.a.cassandra.service.StartupChecks - JMX is not enabled to receive remote connections. Please see cassandra-env.sh for more info.
11:36:14.943 [main] WARN  o.a.cassandra.service.StartupChecks - OpenJDK is not recommended. Please upgrade to the newest Oracle Java release
11:36:14.954 [main] WARN  o.a.cassandra.utils.SigarLibrary - Cassandra server running in degraded mode. Is swap disabled? : false,  Address space adequate? : true,  nofile limit adequate? : false, nproc limit adequate? : true
```

Comment: You have multiple issues. First kill the Cassandra daemon  and try starting Cassandra again and post the error if you see any

Comment: Thanks for your advices.
The error I got is the same as I posted before with "Insufficient disk space to write 572 bytes", after a 90,000-character long message information about cassandra launch. I'll add the WARN messages I got during the launch in the first message, as I cannot copy everything here.

Comment: After some trials and research, I think I found the root of the issue. The `/var`folder was full, with respect to the size it can reach (in my case, due to Nifi logs). Therefore, removing from the `/var` folder any useless file would give space for Cassandra to start. I'll post the comment as answer if the problem is still solved in a few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in a previous comment, it seems that the issue was triggered by the `/var` folder reaching its limit size, because Nifi, that I used for ingesting data, generates big logs in my configuration. Therefore removing useless logs and keeping an eye on the `/var` folder seems to prevent the error.